# React - Internal server error when redirecting to Flask endpoint

Tags: reactjs, flask, internal-server-error

I'm trying to learn how to create a web app using React and Flask. I'm following [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-create-a-react--flask-project) guide.

The frontend server starts fine on port 3000, as does the Flask server on port 5000, which I can tell by successfully accessing it directly in the browser.

To redirect the request to port 5000, I've added `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"` in package.json, as per the guide.

App.js:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/time').then(res => res.json()).then(data =>  {
        setCurrentTime(data.time);
    });
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
        <p>The current time is {currentTime}.</p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

api.py:

```
from flask import Flask
import time
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/time')
def get_current_time():
    print("hi")
    return {"time": time.time()}
```

I expect the page to update with the current time, but what I actually get is "The current time is. 0".
Node gives this error: `Proxy error: Could not proxy request /time from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/.` The developer console reports a 500 internal server error.

I've tried `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"`, `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` and `"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"`, none changed anything.